# How to create a Firefox container dedicated for web search?

Tags: firefox, privacy, google-search, privacy-protection

Is there a way to create a Firefox container dedicated for web search, such as Google? In this way, I can remain logged in for Google in other situations and keep my web searches hidden from Google. The ideal behavior is:

- Whenever I type a keyword from the search bar, Firefox uses the dedicated container to display the search result page.
- Whenever I click on a link in the search result page, Firefox exits this dedicated container.

Comment: I don't know that this is possible, but you may be able to get most of the results you are after by doing your main google searches in a regular tab, but instead of clicking on the result, right click and say "Open in new private tab".

Comment: @davidgo That would require me to visiting non-Google pages in private tabs :(

Comment: Surely that is what you want, otherwise Google will just use Google Analytics on most pages to track your actions through the web?

Comment: I already have blockers that blocks connections to Google analytics. For most sites, I still want to use them normally.

Answer (score 1):

As xuhdev said, use the Multi Container extension. Note that this is not really enough to achieve what you want.

An additional protection would be to use [Cookie Auto-delete](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookie-autodelete/). You will also want to block 3rd party trackers as an additonal precaution with something like [uBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/).

An obvious, additional alternative would be to use a privacy search engine, such as MetaGer, DuckDuckGo, SearX, Startpages, Ecosia, etc.

But really, you can still be easily fingerprinted. For this, check out [Arkenfox.js](https://github.com/arkenfox/user.js), or just use [Mullvad Browser](https://mullvad.net/en/browser), which is forked from Firefox. I assume you don't have a real security threat, or you would want to use [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/download/), or ideally [Tails OS](https://tails.boum.org/).

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure you have the [Multi Container extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/) installed.
2. Use Google to search an arbitrary word. You should now be on a Google search result page.
3. Click on the multi container icon on the toolbar. Click on "Always Open this Tab in...", and select a container that you would dedicate for web searches.
4. Click on the multi container icon on the toolbar. Click on "Manage Containers", and select the container that you would dedicate for web searches. Check the box "Limit to Designated Sites."

Now whenever you search with Google, a tab in the dedicated container would display the search result. Whenever you click on a search result, the page would be displayed outside of the container.

The reason it works is that Google displays search results under the "www.google.com" subdomain. So far I haven't seen any other Google services use this subodmain other than Google Maps, which is also a good service worth restricting anyway. By restricting the domain "www.google.com" to a container and limiting the container to display pages only from "www.google.com", this container effectively becomes a dedicated web search container.